# Fuction accepting any data type

Tags: java, function, object

I want to create a function in Java which will accept any data type parameter and will print it. Here is an attempt:

```java
void get(Object obj){
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

I tried this method by doing it with an integer but that gave a error. Can I make a function which can take pretty much any data type parameter?

Comment: "but that gave a error" - What error?

Comment: [Your code works perfectly fine](http://ideone.com/qVBNA5). Voting to close as "cannot reproduce".

Comment: Try using generics.

Comment: Your code works, but it's not really an method that accepts any data type, it's a a method that accepts an object data type. 

You should work with generics, ie: void <T> get (T obj)

Comment: Please paste the error. Is that all you want to achieve or anything more?

Comment: You mean that for every primitive type's value there is no boxing to the corresponding Object child? `System.out.println` solves that by overloads to all primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println` is the perfect example for such a function. However in reality it's not a single function but a series of them so `println` will be able to accept all types. If you look in `System.out`, you'll find all of these variants of `println`:

```
public void println()
public void println(boolean x)
public void println(char x)
public void println(char x[])
public void println(double x)
public void println(float x)
public void println(int x)
public void println(long x)
public void println(Object x)
public void println(String x)
```

This is what allows it to accept primitives such as `int`, since `int` is not an `Object`, and neither is `char`, `long`, `double` etc